# error of prototype method or my misunderstanding in this task

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

Task

1. Build a function constructor called Question to describe a question. A question should include:
   a) question itself
   b) the answers from which the player can choose the correct one (choose an adequate data structure here, array, object, etc.)
   c) correct answer ( I would use a number for this)
2. Create a couple of questions using the constructr
3. Store them all inside an array
4. Select random question and log it on the console, together with the possible answers (each question should have a number ( Hint: write a method for the Question objects for this task).
5. Use 'prompt' function to ask the user for the correct answer. The user should input the number of the correct answer.
6. Check if the answer is correct and print to the console whether the answer is correct or not(Hint: write another method for this)

My problem: I tried to use method of Question constructor through Question itself and through question1 or question2 etc objects but in output just error :

> Question.randomQuestion is not a function

My solution:

```
function Question(question, answers, correctAnswer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}

Question.prototype.randomQuestion = function(questions) {
    // random number for list
    var randomQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length) + 1;
    console.log(questions[randomQuestion].question)
    // output answers for random question
    for(var i = 0; i < questions[randomQuestion].answers.length; i++) {
        console.log(questions[randomQuestion].answers[i]);
    }

    return questions[randomQuestion];
};

Question.prototype.checkCorrectAnswerOfUser = function(currentObject, choiceOfUser) {
    if (choiceOfUser === currentObject.correctAnswer) console.log('Correct answer!');
    else console.log("I'm sorry, but your answer is wrong...");
};

// pass our questions
var question1 = new Question('Is JavaScript the best programming language?', ['Yes', 'No', "I Don't know"], 0);
var question2 = new Question('Who is Daniil?', ['cloudy man', 'cloudy girl'], 0);
var question3 = new Question('Who is Alin?', ['programmer', 'designer', 'photograph'], 2);
// make the array of questions
var listOfQuestions = [question1, question2, question3];
// save point to the current object in variable
var currentObject = Question.randomQuestion(listOfQuestions);

var choiceOfUser = prompt('Please select the correct answer. (Just type of number)');
```

Comment: `Question.prototype.randomQuestion(listOfQuestions)`

Comment: If you want randomQuestion to act like a pure static function, you don't require to place on the prototype, prototype is used when the `this` context is relevant, and of course this is not the case for a pure static function.  So, you can just do `Question.randomQuestion = function`

Answer (score 0):

change `Question.prototype.randomQuestion` to: `Question.randomQuestion`

Answer (score 0):

The assignment is a bit misleading in step 4:

> Select random question and log it on the console, together with the possible answers (each question should have a number) (Hint: write a method for the Question objects for this task).

Actually those are two tasks:

- selecting a random question from the array
- logging a question (with a number) to the console, and listing its possible answers

You should write two separate procedures for this. The first one (which could be generalised to arbitrary arrays of anything, not just that particular array of questions) should be a plain global function:

```
function getRandomElement(array) {
    …
    return element;
}
```

Only the second one should actually be a method of a question:

```
Question.prototype.display = function() {
    … // use `this` to refer to the instance
};
```

You would call it as `currentQuestion.display()`.